# Angular 4 ngModel Throttle Model Update

Tags: angular, rxjs

We have a data source that exposes the following property:

```
public get CurrentValue()
{
    return this.Record.GetValue(this.Field.PropertyName);
}
public set CurrentValue(value: string)
{
    this.Record.CaptureUndoState();
    this.Record.SetValue(this.Field.PropertyName, value);
}
```

Then we can bind my input field to it via ngModel:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="CurrentValue" />
```

This works great, but we'd like to delay the set of CurrentValue by 500ms, in order to avoid capturing undo states with each key-up. In angular 1.x you could accomplish this with ng-model-options debounce.

Many examples we're coming across uses `ngModelChange` or `Observable.fromEvent` such as the [Debounce Directive](https://github.com/numsu/angular2-debounce/blob/master/src/debounce.directive.ts). These fall short because they still update the source frequently, only delaying a call to another method.

Another alternative we're coming across is to subscribe to some sort of observable that throttles updates. But this appears to fall short as it breaks two-way binding. If `CurrentValue` changes, my input field is no longer updated.

How can my input field watch for changes on a NON-Observable source, while throttling setting the source?

Comment: is `set CurrentValue(...)` gonna return an observable as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

public set CurrentValue(value: string)
{
    _.throttle(() => {
        this.Record.CaptureUndoState();
        this.Record.SetValue(this.Field.PropertyName, value);
    }, 500);
}
```